# How to handle pointers in shared memory?

Tags: c, linux

I'm learning about memory sharing between processes. I know there are problems with pointers in shared memory, but I still want to see what happens when pointers appear in shared memory. So I wrote the following code for testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define INIT( i, u, v ) sem_init(&i, u, v)
#define P( i ) sem_wait(&i)
#define V( i ) sem_post(&i)

struct share_mem {
    char buf[10];
    sem_t s;
    char* ptr;
};

int main() {
    int shm_id = shmget(getpid(), sizeof(share_mem), IPC_CREAT|0600);
    void* ptr = shmat(shm_id, 0, 0);
    share_mem *shared = (share_mem *)ptr;
    shared->ptr = NULL;
    INIT(shared->s, 1, 1);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        wait(0);
        P(shared->s);
        if (shared->ptr == NULL) {
            shared->ptr = new char[10];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            (shared->buf)[i] = i + '0';
            (shared->ptr)[i] = i + '0';
        }
        printf("parent: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("%c ", (shared->buf)[i]);
        }
        printf("\nparent_ptr: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("%c ", (shared->ptr)[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        V(shared->s);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        shared = (share_mem *)shmat(shm_id, 0, 0);
        P(shared->s);
        if (shared->ptr == NULL) {
            shared->ptr = new char[10];
        }
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            (shared->buf)[i] = (i - 5) + '0';
            (shared->ptr)[i] = (i - 5) + '0';
        }
        printf("child: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("%c ", (shared->buf)[i]);
        }
        printf("\nchild_ptr: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("%c ", (shared->ptr)[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        V(shared->s);
    }
    int stat = shmdt((void*)shared);
    if (pid > 0) {
        stat = shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I thought there would be an segmentation fault in this code, because the parent process will use a section of memory that does not exist. However, after compiling and executing with G + +, the output is as follows.

```
child:      0 1 2 3 4 
child_ptr:      0 1 2 3 4 
parent: 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 
parent_ptr: p a r e n t _ p t r
```

The output of `child` and `parent` are expected, but the output of `parent_ptr` is a bit strange. No matter how many times I recompile and run, the output is always the same.

I want to know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers in shared memory act the same as pointers anywhere else; they contain a memory-address that refers to a memory-location.  For user-space programs, that memory-location is expressed as a virtual-memory-address, and when it is dereferenced, the computer's MMU looks up the corresponding physical-memory-address to find the correct page of memory to access, according to the calling process's virtual->physical page-mapping table.

And there's the usual rub with storing pointers in shared memory, if you are accessing that shared memory from different processes -- if the process dereferencing the pointer is not the same process that wrote the pointer, then it's almost certain that that virtual-memory-address will not be valid/translatable for that process.  For example, process A might call `shared->ptr = new char[10];` and thereby place the pointer-value `0x12345678` (or whatever) into the shared-memory region, and process A could later dereference that pointer-value to read or write to those 10 bytes of heap memory without a problem.... but if process B tries to dereference that pointer, process B will invoke undefined behavior (maybe causing a segmentation fault, or maybe just corrupting its own memory space, or etc) because process B never allocated 10 bytes of heap memory at pointer-value `0x12345678` of its own virtual-address-space.

> The output of child and parent are expected, but the output of
> parent_ptr is a bit strange. No matter how many times I recompile and
> run, the output is always the same.

When I run the posted code (on MacOS/X 10.15.6, FWIW), I get this output:

```
$ ./a.out
child:      0 1 2 3 4 
child_ptr:      0 1 2 3 4 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So I believe that what you are seeing is the consequence of having invoked undefined behavior, as mentioned above.  Once undefined behavior has been invoked, all bets are off and anything can happen, depending on the implementation details of the system the program is running on.

My guess is that on your Linux box, the invalid pointer just happens to be pointing to one byte past the start of the storage-location of the "\nparent_ptr: " string constant that you had passed to `printf()` earlier.

Comment: Thank you.Since there will be problems using pointers in shared memory, does this mean that I can't use pointers in shared memory. If I can, how can I use them?

Comment: @AMHTS: Normally, you design your program so as to avoid them.  E.g. if you need some data structure with internal references, have it use array offsets instead of pointers, or something like that.  In principle, you could also relocate all pointers as you use them: figure out the difference between the mapping's original address and your copy's address, and subtract that value from every pointer (with appropriate casting) before you dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use pointers in shared memory. What you need to do, broadly, is this:

- The process that creates the shared memory segment (which is also the first process to attach to it) stores the address of the pointer returned by `shmat` *in the shared memory segment*.
- Subsequent processes that attach to the segment compare the address returned by *their* `shmat` call to the one stored in the segment.
- If the addresses do not match, use `shmdt` to detach from the segment, then re-attach to the segment, supplying the address stored by the *first* process as the second argument to `shmat`, instead of using `0`.

This will force all processes to attach the shared memory segment at the same virtual address, meaning pointers will line up across process boundaries.

This is a bit of dark magic, and seems dangerous at first blush, but I've seen the technique used in a very significant codebase to great effect and without problems.

See the `UTIL_Share` function in [Reference Standard M](https://gitlab.com/Reference-Standard-M/rsm/-/blob/main/util/share.c) for an example.

Comment: The problem is that if the address selected by process #1 happens to already be in use in process #2, the last `shmat` fails and you have no way to recover.

Answer (score 0):

As we know that shared memory are regions in memory declared as sections that will be used simultaneously by several processes. meaning this memory segment will be seen by several processes, RIGHT? and as a consequence, several processes might try to alter this memory area simultaneously and thus semaphores are used to synchronize their access as mutually exclusive.

So you used the shmget() system call to allocate a shared memory segment and the shmget() returns an identifier that is used to add it to the memory page table of the process. this identifier is used in the shmat() system call that returns you a pointer you can now use to place data in this shared memory.

However, since pointers contain virtual addresses, you need to be careful while using pointers. Because the same segment might be attached in a different virtual address in other processes, so a pointer referring to one memory area in one process might refer to a different memory area in another process. That is the reason behind this undefined behavior and may cause a segmentation fault if a process wants to access location corrupted by another process.